# Wait until jQuery accordion panel is collapsed until opening another

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, accordion

I have the jQuery UI Accordion set up to open and close on `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`. The problem with this is that unfortunately the closing animation abruptly stops when switching to another panel quickly.

I don't want this to happen, but I want to keep the slide animation. Is there a way to not open the panel if another is still in the process of closing?

HTML:

```
<div id="navitems">
    <h3>Home</h3>
    <div>Home Panel</div>
    <h3>Contact</h3>
    <div>Contact Panel</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#navitems").accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
    event: "mouseover mouseleave",
});
```

I did a fair amount of research on this and came up with nothing useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just use the mouseover event?

```
$("#navitems").accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
    event: "mouseover",
});
```

This seems to behave the way you are describing: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eNd9n/1/)